# grepping specific data from json (multiple lines)

Tags: python, json

I am pulling some json data and trying to extract specific lines/data from it.  I think I should be able to use grep in this scenario and was wondering if I can get some help.  Here is what I have:

```
 [ 'vlans VLAN10 vlan-id 10',
 'vlans VLAN100 vlan-id 100',
 'vlans VLAN20 vlan-id 20',
 'vlans VLAN30 vlan-id 30',
 'vlans default vlan-id 1',
 'vlans vlan111 vlan-id 111',
 'vlans vlan222 vlan-id 222',]
```

Here is what I am trying to use:

```
config_json = results.json()
config_json_dumps = json.dumps(config_json)
pattern = 'vlan-id'
for vlans in config_json_dumps:
    if re.search(pattern, vlans):
        print(pattern)
```

But I just get a blank response with code 0.

Comment: Don't use `grep` to process JSON. Use a tool specialized to it, `jq`.

Comment: `for vlans in config_json_dumps` is iterating over individual characters in the JSON string. Why are you looping over the string instead of the list in `config_json`?

Comment: What does this have to do with `grep`? That's a shell tool, not part of Python.

Comment: It seems like you don't understand what JSON is.

Comment: You have a simple list, so use `[x for x in config_json if 'vlan-id' in x]`, see https://ideone.com/ytToGw. This has nothing to do with regex in fact, it is a mere `str.contains` case.

Comment: if somethink doesn'twork (or gives error) then first you could use `print(...)` and `print(type(...))`to see what you have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"` - and this should show you that you get single chars in variable `vlans`

Comment: in your example all lines have `'vlan-id'` and checking this is useless. If you need number after `'vlan-id'` then you would ned regex `'vlan-id (\d+)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.json()` gives you list of strings and you don't have to convert it to string. And to check if line has `vlan-id` you don't need `regex`

```
config_json = [
 'vlans VLAN10 vlan-id 10',
 'vlans VLAN100 vlan-id 100',
 'vlans VLAN20 vlan-id 20',
 'vlans VLAN30 vlan-id 30',
 'vlans default vlan-id 1',
 'vlans vlan111 vlan-id 111',
 'vlans vlan222 vlan-id 222',
]

pattern = 'vlan-id'

for line in config_json:
    if pattern in line:
        print(line)
```

---

In your example all lines have `'vlan-id'` so checking this seems useless.

But if you would like to get number after `'vlan-id'` then it would have sense - and it would need `regex`

```
config_json = [
 'vlans VLAN10 vlan-id 10',
 'vlans VLAN100 vlan-id 100',
 'vlans VLAN20 vlan-id 20',
 'vlans VLAN30 vlan-id 30',
 'vlans default vlan-id 1',
 'vlans vlan111 vlan-id 111',
 'vlans vlan222 vlan-id 222',
]
        
import re

for line in config_json:
    result = re.search('vlan-id (\d+)', line)
    if result:
        print(result[1])
```

Comment: Ok I figured out what I was doing wrong and I have been able to get this working with all the examples here.  Thank you all for your help.